VS code python error can't find imported file
So I am using python and I have the following schema of files:
- 10.Testing (parent folder)
  -- files (folder)
    |__  __init__.py (empty file)
    |__simple_functions.py
  -- tests (folder)
    |__ test_simple_functions.py
    |__  __init__.py (empty file)

10.Testing: This is my parent folder, which contains the 2 folders, tests and files.
files: This is a subfolder in my parent folder. It contains the Python file simple_functions.py where I have defined some functions.
tests: This is another subfolder in my parent folder. It contains the Python file test_simple_functions.py where I am writing my test cases for my functions in simple_functions.py.
Just to clarify, I am not 100% if this should be the file structure of a repo. If not please do tell.
In the test_simple_functions.py  I have added  the following code :
# testing the file simple_functions.py

from files.simple_functions import *



def main():
    squared_function(2)





if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()




So I am using VS Code and trying to execute the code of simple_functions.py but I cannot it says:

Traceback (most recent call last):   File
"\tests\test_simple_functions.py", line 3, in 
from files.simple_functions import *

for example from workspace folder:
py tests/test_simpl_functions.py
from tests folder:
tests> py .\test_simple_functions.py
No matter where I run the file:
whether I am in tests folder, workspace folder, files folder it doesn't work.
but in my test_simple_functions.py
My workspace / exporer says parent file 10.Testing
I tried terminal bash , powershell and cmd.
it highlights the "files.simple_function" in light blue/green (not sure about the color lol) and VS code recognises that there are functions there and I can use them and tab them to autocomplete , so what is the problem ?
What should I be doing ?
is this the best practise?
I tried running the code in multiple folders and testing the code it doesnt work but recognises it in vs code

Your directory is like so:
Testing/                           # Parent folder
│
├── files/                            # Subfolder for Python modules
│   ├── __init__.py                   # Makes files a Python package
│   └── simple_functions.py           # Python file with function definitions
│
└── tests/                            # Subfolder for tests
    ├── __init__.py                   # Makes tests a Python package
    └── test_simple_functions.py      # Test cases for simple_functions.py



To run test_simple_functions.py so that it sees the tests package, cd into Testing and run like so :

python -m tests.test_simple_functions

this way, python sees both packages.

Inside the code you wish to run, you can ask python to watch the parent directory by adding:

import sys
sys.path.append('..')  # Adds the parent directory to python path


NB: This must be before you make your import.
